# How to monitor key logs from onscreen keyboard on linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard, on-screen-keyboard, keylogger

I have been doing research on key loggers and found out that lkl and logkeys doesn't work on onscreen keyboard. In that case how to log keys from onboard?

Comment: What OS and possibly what application, if the keyboard is specific to it?

Comment: Os :Parrot,Keyboard :onboard